# remove the node that does not have particular value in XML using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to remove node in the XML output that does not have `Zcode=XYZ`? SQL output is:

```
[[00000016,, 04,, XYZ], [00000016,, 04,,]]
```

Code that uses JAXB logic to generated XML:

```
var abclist: Seq[Row] = x.getAs[Row]("TVchannels").asInstanceOf[Seq[Row]]
          
if (abclist != null) {

    abclist.foreach(gap => {

        var abcobj: abc = new abc()
        abcobj.setChanneltune(checknull(gap.getAs[String]("_channeltune")))
        abcobj.setZCode(checknull(gap.getAs[String]("Zcode")))
        abcobj.setFCode(checknull(gap.getAs[String]("Fcode")))
```

In XML output the second node should be removed; it does not have `Zcode` and the node should not be displayed in output.

```
<abc Zcode="XYZ" FCode="04" SMTPESPcode="00000016"/>
<abc FCode="04" SMTPESPcode="00000016"/>
```

Comment: can you share full XML data for input?  so that I can give you the code?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,
the below approach will solve your use case,
input xml file contents taken,

```
<root>
    <tvchannels>
        <tvchannel>
              <SMTPESPcode>00000016<\SMTPESPcode>
              <FCode>04<\FCode>
              <Zcode>XYZ<\Zcode>
         <\tvchannel>
         <tvchannel>
              <SMTPESPcode>00000016<\SMTPESPcode>
              <FCode>04<\FCode>
              <Zcode><\Zcode>
         <\tvchannel>    
    <\tvchannels>
<\root>
```

code for reading your input as xml file follow https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

```
val df =spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag", "tvchannel").load("file:///home/ubuntu/input/tvchannles.xml");
df.show()

/*
+-----------+-----+-----+
|SMTPESPcode|FCode|Zcode|
+-----------+-----+-----+
|   00000016|   04|  XYZ|
|   00000016|   04|     |
+-----------+-----+-----+
*/

df.filter("Zcode != ''").show()

/*
+-----------+-----+-----+
|SMTPESPcode|FCode|Zcode|
+-----------+-----+-----+
|   00000016|   04|  XYZ|
+-----------+-----+-----+
*/

// your remaining spark logic.
```

or read it as a Seq:

```
val df = Seq((00000016,04,"XYZ"),(00000016,04,"")).toDF("SMTPESPcode","FCode","Zcode")
df.show()
/*
+-----------+-----+-----+
|SMTPESPcode|FCode|Zcode|
+-----------+-----+-----+
|   00000016|   04|  XYZ|
|   00000016|   04|     |
+-----------+-----+-----+
*/

df.filter("Zcode != ''").show()

/*
+-----------+-----+-----+
|SMTPESPcode|FCode|Zcode|
+-----------+-----+-----+
|   00000016|   04|  XYZ|
+-----------+-----+-----+
*/

// your remaining spark logic.
```

Comment: i am generating the nodes using spark sql and then using function collect_set(__channeltune,Zocde,Code) as abc and passing abc to JAXB and then generating XML ,but you are reading the xml and then removing the node